# What does glTranslatef function is translating in this code?

Tags: opengl, transformation

I understand translation from mathematics view where we can have a triangle with a certain coordinates. We can translate this triangle by multiplying the coordinates of the triangle (expressed in the form of a matrix) by a translation vector.

In the code below, I could not see what glTranslate () is translating since we havent drawn anything yet. What are we translating? Are we applying the translation to some default objects or something?

```
         void display(void)
     {
     glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glRotatef ((GLfloat) shoulder, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glPushMatrix();
     glScalef (2.0, 0.5, 1.0);
     glutWireCube (1.0);
     glPopMatrix();
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glRotatef ((GLfloat) elbow, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glPushMatrix();
     glScalef (2.0, 0.5, 1.0);
     glutWireCube (1.0);
     glPopMatrix();
     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(1.6, 0.22, 0.0);
     glRotatef ((GLfloat) finger, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     glScalef (0.6, 0.1, 0.08);
     glutWireCube (1.0);
     glPopMatrix();
     glPopMatrix();
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     glutSwapBuffers();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each gl* commad there changes the state of the OpenGl state machine. so the `glTranslatef` command sets the translation of whatever you draw after that command.

Its like setting a global World Transform matrix to that particular translation. All the vertices you draw after that call to `glTranslatef` will be rendered with that translation applied, until of course when you tell OpenGL to change that translation again with `glTranslatef` or something similar.

Comment: "Its like setting a global World Transform matrix to that particular translation", Well that does it, now its making sense to me.

Comment: Is this a newer OpenGL function or an older fixed-function pipeline one?

Comment: @Coburn , This is old opengl.